# Sampling with and without replacement

Tags: python, sampling

I'm trying to run a sampling with and without replacement and look over the means.
I'm very confused as to why sampling without replacement results in the same means. So, I was wondering if my coding was wrong.

Here's my code

```
def sample(q2array, replace = True):
  sampling = np.random.choice(q2array, # set your input array
                        size = len(q2array), # set the length of the return object
                        replace = replace)
  return(sampling)

replace1=sample(array, True)
print('Mean of replacement 1:', np.mean(replace1))
replace2=sample(array, True)
print('Mean of replacement 2:', np.mean(replace2))
replace3=sample(array, True)
print('Mean of replacement 3:', np.mean(replace3))

noreplace1=sample(array, False)
print('Mean of without replacement 1:', np.mean(noreplace1))
noreplace2=sample(array, False)
print('Mean of without replacement 2:', np.mean(noreplace2))
noreplace3=sample(array, False)
print('Mean of without replacement 3:', np.mean(noreplace3))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `size = len(q2array)` and `replace=False` it simply takes each element once in random order. Or with other words, you're just doing a `mean(array)`.

If `array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and you run:

```
np.random.choice(array, size=len(array), replace=False)
```

You'll get:

```
array([8, 3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 9, 7, 6])
```

You have 9 values and it takes 9 without putting them back, so there can be no variance here.

For example, if you do:

```
size = len(q2array)-1
```

Then you finally get some variance:

```
Mean of replacement 1: 3.25
Mean of replacement 2: 3.875
Mean of replacement 3: 4.125
Mean of without replacement 1: 4.75
Mean of without replacement 2: 5.375
Mean of without replacement 3: 4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sampling `len(array)` samples from your `array` without replacement. This means that you sample each element of `array` exactly once. Therefore the mean of the sampling without replacement `noreplace1.mean()` corresponds exactly to `array.mean()`.

Maybe to understand what is happening better you need to understand the `replace` flag better. If `replace=True` then it might happen that the same element of `array` is sampled several times. Therefore, `replace1` can contain elements of `array` more than once and the mean of `replace1` varies.

If you want `noreplace` samples with different means, you need to sample less elements (<`len(array)`) from the `array`.